What does getting a non-significant log(theta) mean?
I am running a simple model in R testing if fish density (nr of fish per volume) depends on the depth in the area. There are a lot of areas with zero fish so I use a zeroinflated model (package pscl::zeroinfl in R).
Model <- zeroinfl(FishDensity ~Depth, data = myData, dist = "negbin", 
                   na.action = na.omit)

These are the results:
Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.33750    0.24254  22.007   <2e-16 ***
Depth        0.03446    0.01367   2.521   0.0117 *  
Log(theta)   0.08603    0.14003   0.614   0.5390    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 1.893173   0.288799   6.555 5.55e-11 ***
Depth       0.007084   0.016472   0.430    0.667    

In the count model coefficients I get a non-significant log(theta).
What does this mean? Should I dismiss the model?
Depth in itself is significant.
I am a novice at statistics so please try to explain it in simple terms.

What package is this function from? Can you explain more about the details of the model here? I presume this is some form of zero inflated GLM but there's no indication of exactly how it's set up, what the link function is, the role of $\theta$ in this model etc

Glancing at the documentation of pscl::zeroinfl (which this question might be about?) $\theta$ is the negative binomial dispersion, so it has nothing to do with zero-inflation and a hypothesis test in the log scale likely isn't too meaningful.

What happens if you fit a zero-inflated Poisson instead of a negative binomial?

The result is very similar if I use poisson (except I don't get a log(theta) value).

tl;dr it's probably not anything you care about.
Coefficient tables like this are always (in my experience) testing the estimated coefficient against a null value of zero. In this case, since we are estimating log(theta), this is testing against a null value of theta=1, which for a negative binomial distribution corresponds to a geometric distribution.
So you're failing to reject the null hypothesis that the conditional distribution of (non-zero-inflated) counts is geometric.
For what it's worth, in a similar vein the test of the intercept of the zero-inflation component is testing against a null hypothesis that logit(zi_prob)==0 at the baseline (Depth=0), or in other words that the zero-inflation probability is 0.5 at the baseline. In this case you can strongly reject that null hypothesis, but again this probably isn't something you actually care about.
Let's see what happens if you fit to non-zero-inflated, non-overdispersed data (i.e. simulated Poisson counts):
library(pscl)
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=rpois(10000, lambda = 1))
summary(zeroinfl(x ~ 1, dist = "negbin", data = dd))

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.007322   0.010178   0.719    0.472
Log(theta)  10.010213  39.315293   0.255    0.799

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -9.863     39.895  -0.247    0.805

In this case theta (and log(theta)) is approaching infinity and the log-odds of zero-inflation are approaching -Inf. (The standard errors are also huge, because the Wald approximation breaks down in these limits.)
If you want to test for the presence of zero-inflation and overdispersion you need to do something more complicated (e.g. see functions provided by the DHARMa package).

Thanks for the answer!

If the answer solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...
